# sharepoint domain alias

Tags: domain-name-system, sharepoint, alias

my problem is that i couldn't bind sharepoint webapp to another domain alias ,we are running win2k3 and have dns server ,sharepoint server has site1.domain.com (host(a) record of the server ip)  ,now i want it to map to another site2.domain.com ,so i created domain alias of type cname record with FQDN of site2.domain.com and target FQDN is site1.domain.com ,to test it i ping site2.domain.com and it return from site1.domain.com ,thus i think alias is working ,now when i try to access sharepoint using site2.domain.com ,it says Bad Request (Invalid Hostname) ,note that sharepoint use port 80,where is the trick?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok i found it ,what i needed to do is going to CA /Operation tab and in AAM add internal url ,simple as that